# Read Excel in Android

Tags: android, excel, apache-poi, jexcelapi

Currently I'm working on android development.  As the requirement stated, the application should able to read the Excel files for data input.

As other people start with this topic, I have go through with [**Java Excel Api**](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) and [**Apache POI**](http://poi.apache.org/), but both need to have some modification to fit my requirement:

*JExcel API*:
  - Cannot support XLSX

*Apache POI*:
  - Support well for XLS files
  - To support XLSX in Dalvik, you need to overcome 64K and javax library, or use the port version (i.e. from [Andrew Kondratev](https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX))
  - File size will increase 2.4MB

But do we have other option to work with Excel files in Android 4 or below?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those application who need to work with full functional excel files (i.e. drawing, VBA etc... ), you should go with ***Apache POI***, it's plain but still the best solution for that now.

However, if you just need to read the Excel, it maybe good to go with JavaScript solution.  With [**js-xlsx**](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library, you can transfer Excel files into JSON.  And the library size is small, just 395KB (only include *xlsx.core.min.js*)

I believe this not the best solution:
  - `WebView` need to work with `UI Thread`, it may block the UI when reading large Excel file.
  - Performance issue
But you could change this to other JavaScript engine like `Rhino` or `V8` to fix these issues.

Here is the code

***Interface for callback:***

```java
public interface ExcelReaderListener {
    void onReadExcelCompleted(List<String> stringList);
}
```

***MainActivity:***

```java
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setMessage("message")
            .setTitle("title")
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    new FileChooser(MainActivity.this, new String[]{"xls", "xlsx"})
                            .setFileListener(new FileChooser.FileSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void fileSelected(File file) {
                                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                                    progressDialog.setTitle("title");
                                    progressDialog.setMessage("message");
                                    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                                    ExcelReaderListener excelReaderListener = MainActivity.this;

                                    progressDialog.show();
                                    try {
                                        final WebView webView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
                                        new JSExcelReader(filePath, webView, excelReaderListener);
                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                        Log.e("Import excel error", ex.getMessage());
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .showDialog();
                }
            })
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onReadExcelCompleted(List<String> stringList) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Parse Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    // Write into DB
    ...
}
```

***Interface for user to select excel file:***

https://rogerkeays.com/simple-android-file-chooser

***JSExcelReader: (Core part to read excel and transform it to ArrayList)***

```java
public class JSExcelReader {

    private ExcelReaderListener callback;

    public JSExcelReader(String filePath, final WebView webView, ExcelReaderListener callback) {
        this.callback = callback;

        File file = new File(filePath);

        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            // convert file to Base64
            if (file.length() > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                Log.e("File too big", "file too big");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            int offset = 0;
            int numRead;
            while (offset < bytes.length &&
            (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
                offset += numRead;
            }

            if (offset < bytes.length)
                throw new Exception("Could not completely read file");

            final String b64 = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);

            // feed the string into webview and get the result
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/AndroidParseExcel.html");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    webView.evaluateJavascript("convertFile('" + b64 + "');", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                            parseJSON(value);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Convert Excel failure", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void parseJSON(String jsonString) {
        try {
            // return value is something like "{\n\"Sheet1\":\n[\"title\"...
            // you need to remove those escape character first
            JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(jsonString.substring(1, jsonString.length() - 1)
                                                            .replaceAll("\\\\n", "")
                                                            .replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"")
                                                            .replaceAll("\\\\\\\\\"", "'"));
            JSONArray sheet1 = jsonRoot.optJSONArray("Sheet1");
            List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

            JSONObject jsonObject;
            for (int i = 0; i < sheet1.length(); i++) {
                jsonObject = sheet1.getJSONObject(i);

                stringList.add(jsonObject.optString("title"));
            }

            callback.onReadExcelCompleted(stringList);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Error in parse JSON", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

***AndroidParseExcel.html:*** (You should put this and the JavaScript library into *asset* folder)

```
<html>
<script src="file:///android_asset/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<head></head>
<body>
</body>
<script type ="text/javascript">

    "use strict";

    var X = XLSX;

    function convertFile(b64data) {
        var wb = X.read(b64data, {type: 'base64',WTF: false});

        var result = {};
        wb.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
            var roa = X.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(wb.Sheets[sheetName]);
            if(roa.length > 0){
                result[sheetName] = roa;
            }
        });

        return JSON.stringify(result, 2, 2);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can this work on an emulator? I keep getting out of memory errors even though the excel file size is 7mb only.

Comment: excellent circumvention. just that i used jsonarray directly instead of arraylist +1

Answer (score 0):

To read xlsx file

Add following dependencies, in build gradle

```
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.0'

implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.0'
```

use following code

```
    import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

    val file= this.javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("data.xlsx")
    val pkg: OPCPackage = OPCPackage.open(file)
    val wb = XSSFWorkbook(pkg)

    val rowNumber = 0

    val columnNumber = 1
    val sheet0 = wb.getSheetAt(0)
    println(sheet0.getRow(rowNumber).getCell(columnNumber))
```

[image]

Since its inside the Junit testing, the file variable is read data.xlsx from resources directory (At root of resources.)